# Upload to dropbox(image/Pdf) from Drive getting empty pages

Tags: node.js, dropbox-api

```
var path = '{\"path\": \"' + jsonData.folder + '/' + jsonData.file + '.' + _file_Extension + '\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false}';
_getFileMetadata(_file_id, req.body.Trigger, (function (filepath) {
    var buf = fs.createReadStream(filepath);
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.body.auth.access_token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Dropbox-API-Arg': path

        },
        body: buf
    };
    request(options, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            res.send('error');
        } else {
            res.send({resultdata: response.body});
        }
    });
}));
```

The code is working fine for image, but incase of PDf its giving empty PDF pages no text

Comment: Your code doesn't show what API endpoint you're using, but it's presumably [https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload). That endpoint will just upload whatever bytes you give it, so make sure your `buf` contains the correct data that you want to upload. You can also use [`content_hash`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/content-hash) to verify the remote data matches the local data.

Comment: Thanks Greg, it was my fault ,i was creating stream from base64 encoded data, now its working fine.